# How to filter out repeated keystrokes like "uu" or two consecutive blank spaces and automatically turn them into one single character like "u" and " "

Tags: external-keyboard

Cheap Bluetooth keyboards have some serious drawbacks that could be easily avoided by software. I bought one for 7 Eur and nearly half the times I hit "u" I get "uu" or "uuu", which is clearly because of faulty hardware since it doesn't happen to any other vocal or symbol and no, it has nothing to do with leaving a key pressed in order to get something like "uuuuu".

Then I got a somewhat more expensive model (15 Eur) and about one in 4 times I hit the space bar I get two consecutive blank spaces and not one, unless I hit it very slowly, carefully and in the exact center of the key.

This could be easily avoided by purchasing a 70 Eur keyboard unless you are poor like me, and the other option would be to have Android filter out repeated characters that are typed very quickly (with a time threshold like, e.g. 'filter out any repeated character that is typed 100 ms after the first one'), thus effectively turning my dreadful double blanks and "uu"s into single blanks and single spaces respectively, without me having to spend more money that I can afford right now.

Please give me a soluuution. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.guidingtech.com/ways-to-fix-keyboard-typing-lag-on-android

Comment: @alecks Nothing to do with my quuestion, but I can't yet vote down. Thanks anyway.

Comment: one can't vote down comments

Comment: @alecxs That didn´t use to be the case. I haven´t been here for a long time.

Comment: What phone are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT #3: ... "External Keyboard Helper Pro"  $ 1.49 US, Google Play Store, does indeed have that setting, and so far is the only app I've found which I'm certain does.

EDIT #2: ... Confirmed: some phones don't have that setting except perhaps when an external/physical keyboard is attached, in which case I'd suggest using the Search field in your phone's Settings to find "physical keyboard" (worked on 2 diff phones here each with diff locations for it within Settings), or "external keyboard", or just "keyboard"...  And again, as a last resort you could probably find another general Keyboard app at Google Play/Store which does have that setting, try using Google Search to find which apps include it, such as "android keyboard app with key repeat delay setting" (I've yet to see a computer/system without it since 1983, it's often one of the first settings I personalize whenever using a new system; I'm old-school IT/Tech/programmer)...  HTH...

EDIT #1:  ... Thx to a helpful reply here, it appears different phones have different Accessibility settings...  (I'd incorrectly assumed something that Fundamental would also be Universal; my bad, sigh, lol)...   I have a Samsung Galaxy S10 with Android 12; my fiance's Moto w/11 is completely different, I've just discovered; I'll try to find the setting in hers and re-edit soon...

ORIG:

Android OS-level setting: Accessibility/Interaction and Dexterity/Bounce Keys (similar to Key Repeat Rate sliders in Windows/etc.). This "should" apply to any key input, whether on screen, external, etc, tho I don't have an external keyboard for a phone to try it out;

If it doesn't, then try finding/using a different keyboard app which does have this setting directly within it (I should think most do?  Google search it if needed), not just at the OS (Android) level.

Comment: AFAIK, this accessibility setting may only be available on Samsung devices (checked on Galaxy M12) but not Android universally; it's not available on Google Pixel 3a. Thus, it might help if you could [edit] and mention the device model. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, thx @Andrew T., had assumed Accessibility was Universal; added my phone specs, checking others now, will re-edit...